# from Gui import * in python 3?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, importerror

I'm trying this:

```
import os, sys
from Gui import *
import Image as PIL
import ImageTk

class ImageBrowser(Gui):

    def __init__(self):
        Gui.__init__(self)

        self.button = self.bu(command=self.quit, relief=FLAT)

    def image_loop(self, dirname='.'):

        files = os.listdir(dirname)
        for file in files:
            try:
                self.show_image(file)
                print (file)
                self.mainloop()
            except IOError:
                continue
            except:
                break

    def show_image(self, filename):

        image = PIL.open(filename)
        self.tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.button.config(image=self.tkpi)

def main(script, dirname='.'):
    g = ImageBrowser()
    g.image_loop(dirname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv)
```

I'm getting an error that says: 
    from Gui import *
    ImportError: No module named Gui

I'm assuming "from Gui import *" doesn't work in python 3, does anyone know how to do this in python 3? Thank you so much (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the [Gui module that comes with Swampy](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/Gui.html), then
in order to use `Gui` with Python3, you'll need to install the [Python3 version of Swampy](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html).